# Rigify: Is it safe to regenerate the rig after I manually painted weights?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify

I understand that:

1. Rigify generates deforming bones on a specific layer, and I can manually adjust (paint) weights after I generate the rig.
2. I can make change on my metarig and regenerate the rig.

My problem is, do these two features work together? For example if I generate a human rig, manually paint some weights, add a tail on the metarig, and then regenerate the rig, would my manually-painted weights remain untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the weights are stored in the vertex groups of the mesh that have the same names as the bones (*DEF-spine.006*, *DEF-hand.R*, etc). Regenerating the rig will not touch them.

Just don't use *Parent To > With Automatic Weights*. This will override your weight painting for sure. You can use *Parent To > With Empty Groups* (<kbd>P</kbd>) to parent the mesh to the rig without changing the weights.

If you separate a part of the mesh, such as the tail, it should be safe to use *Parent To > With Automatic Weights* for the tail only. After this operation, join the body mesh with the tail mesh again.

You also can make a backup copy of the mesh and restore the saved weights with the *Data Transfer* modifier if they got messed up for some reason.